# Best way to export my library images

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-file-loader

I've developed a library which has some images.

I'm using `file-loader` in order to export them in my production into a `res` folder. So my distribution folder look as follow

```
./dist
--- my.core.js
--- my.core.css
--+ res
     --- img1.png
     --- img2.png
```

The problem is when a client uses my library he has to put this `res` folder in his main url.

My question is how do I make `webpack/file-loader` search the `res` folder in relative to the `my.core.js`. so my clients will simply put my library dist folder where ever they want in their server. without moving the `res` folder somewhere else.

`url-loader` is solving my problem, but i do not want to embed my images in my `js` files

Comment: What about base64 encoding the images into the bundle?

Comment: I wrote in my post that `url-loader` doing it for me but i don't want to.. cause this resources might be big, and i don't want the client to "download" all my resources. There are rare used resources also that i don't want to download as long as there is no need for them